# JsRender: how to get value from map with specified key

Tags: jsrender

well I render my data into my page like this:

```
$('#component_data').html($('#component_data_tpl').render(result, extra_opts));
```

here 'result' is a big map returned from my ajax request, which contains all data, e.g.,

```
result: { data1: { 'a': 1, 'b':2}, data2: {...}, ... }
```

so how to render data1['a'], when I know for sure the key is 'a' in my template code without a loop to iterate all values in data1? Do I have to create a helper function?

---

**edit:**

sorry, maybe it's not a good example above.
i'm iterating data1:

```
{{props data1}}
    {{>key}}
{{/props}}
```

however, I want to get data from data2, whose keys are the same as those in data1. Is there a way like:

```
{{props data1}}
    {{>key}}
    {{> data2[key]}}
{{/props}}
```

to do this?
All I know now is to use a helper function, then pass (key, #data.parent) to resolve associated data value, but writing a helper function every time is a bit tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

Yes, for example you can write:

```
{{props data1 ~data2=data2}}
  {{:key}} {{:prop}} {{:~data2[key]}}
{{/props}}
```

which will give

```
a 1 val1
```

with

```
{ data1: { 'a': 1, ...}, data2: { 'a': 'val1'...}, ... }
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's not a good example in the question. It's like this, I'm iterating an array, e.g., an id list, then I want to render data from another associated map with current id.